# Show UTC in timestamp Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle SQL, this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2021-08-11 16:25:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
```

Returns:
`11-AUG-21 04.25.54.000000000 PM`

However, my input timestamp also contains UTC: `2021-08-11 16:25:54 UTC`

Desired result:
`11-AUG-21 04.25.54.000000000 PM UTC`

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ.html#GUID-1728EE3E-EC0C-4FA8-B404-99C0A445CE82) specify to include `Z`... However this does not work:

```
--Invalid date format
SELECT to_timestamp('2021-08-11 16:25:54 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS Z') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need `to_timestamp_tz()` instead of `to_timestamp`, and secondly you need to specify correct [format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41085/sqlqr07001.htm#SQLQR977): `TZR` instead of `Z`:

```
-- TZR = time zone region
SELECT to_timestamp_tz('2021-08-11 16:25:54 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work unfortunately... Error `ORA-01857: not a valid time zone`

Comment: @proximitytopie Something is wrong with your data. Please provide your real data. You can check that it works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0be3a7216a924f4d61bb277ba93df76

Comment: And I wish it did work because I want UTC to be included by calling (a variant of) the TO_TIMESTAMP functions

Comment: @proximitytopie something is wrong with your question: you asked about converting string with 'UTC' in the string to timestamp with time zone, but marked as correct the answer without 'UTC' in the string...

Comment: Hi, can you troubleshoot your answer and give me a version that works?

Comment: Should be `TZR` rather than `TZD`. However, for `UTC` it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `at time zone`

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2021-08-11 16:25:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') at time zone 'UTC' dt
FROM DUAL;
```

**EDIT**

Correct version, thanks to @WernfriedDomscheit

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(to_timestamp('2021-08-11 16:25:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'UTC') ts
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This may fail, i.e. it depends on current user session time zone. In fact it runs `FROM_TZ(to_timestamp('2021-08-11 16:25:54', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), SESSIONTIMEZONE) at time zone 'UTC'`